# Elasticsearch Bulk indexing creates a lot of disk read OPS

Tags: elasticsearch

I've created an index I use for logging.

This means there are mostly writes, and some searches once in a while.
In the phase of the first loading, I'm using several clients to concurrently index documents using the bulk API.

At first, indexing takes 200 ms for a bulk of 5000 documents.
As time goes by, the indexing time increases, and gets to 1000-4500 ms.

I am using an EC2 c3.8xl machine with 32 cores, and 60 GB of memory, with an IO provisioned volume set to 7000 IOPS.

I have 10 shards, no replicas, all on the same machine.
ATM, there are some 1.5 billion records in the index.

Looking at the metrics, I see that the CPU and memory are fine, the write IOPS are at 300, but the read IOPS have slowly gone up and got to 7000.

How come I'm only indexing, but most of the IOPS are read?

My settings are:

```
threadpool.bulk.type: fixed
threadpool.bulk.size: 32                 # availableProcessors
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 1000

# Indices settings
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 50%

indices.cache.filter.expire: 6h

bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

and I've change the index settings to:

```
{"index":{"refresh_interval":"60m",
    "translog":
        {"flush_threshold_size":"1gb",
        "flush_threshold_ops":"50000"}
    }
}
```

I also tried "refresh_interval":"-1"

Please let me know what else I need to provide if needed (settings, logs, metrics). Here are the node stats:

```
"_all": {

    "primaries": {
        "docs": {
            "count": 1473959582,
            "deleted": 1376161
        },
        "store": {
            "size_in_bytes": 497545621011,
            "throttle_time_in_millis": 102780138
        },
        "indexing": {
            "index_total": 416653525,
            "index_time_in_millis": 679407284,
            "index_current": 0,
            "delete_total": 0,
            "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
            "delete_current": 0,
            "noop_update_total": 1,
            "is_throttled": false,
            "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        },
        "get": {
            "total": 2943640,
            "time_in_millis": 15160148,
            "exists_total": 1445558,
            "exists_time_in_millis": 7460238,
            "missing_total": 1498082,
            "missing_time_in_millis": 7699910,
            "current": 0
        },
        "search": {
            "open_contexts": 0,
            "query_total": 70,
            "query_time_in_millis": 12238,
            "query_current": 0,
            "fetch_total": 2,
            "fetch_time_in_millis": 23,
            "fetch_current": 0
        },
        "merges": {
            "current": 0,
            "current_docs": 0,
            "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "total": 4184,
            "total_time_in_millis": 128875711,
            "total_docs": 1282672895,
            "total_size_in_bytes": 429203874419
        },
        "refresh": {
            "total": 1930,
            "total_time_in_millis": 1816632
        },
        "flush": {
            "total": 7774,
            "total_time_in_millis": 4783754
        },
        "warmer": {
            "current": 0,
            "total": 23565,
            "total_time_in_millis": 1792
        },
        "filter_cache": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 184938864,
            "evictions": 0
        },
        "id_cache": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
        },
        "fielddata": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "evictions": 0
        },
        "percolate": {
            "total": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0,
            "memory_size_in_bytes": -1,
            "memory_size": "-1b",
            "queries": 0
        },
        "completion": {
            "size_in_bytes": 0
        },
        "segments": {
            "count": 368,
            "memory_in_bytes": 877782264,
            "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 23671280,
            "index_writer_max_memory_in_bytes": 5368709120,
            "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 19674480,
            "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0
        },
        "translog": {
            "operations": 213819,
            "size_in_bytes": 19598986
        },
        "suggest": {
            "total": 0,
            "time_in_millis": 0,
            "current": 0
        },
        "query_cache": {
            "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "evictions": 0,
            "hit_count": 0,
            "miss_count": 0
        },
        "recovery": {
            "current_as_source": 0,
            "current_as_target": 0,
            "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you index a document it has to go look for that ID to know if it needs to mark an older version of a document as deleted. As your index grows the number of segments naturally goes up too. Thus, ES must perform more seeks to find a given ID. I suspect if you did an optimization on the index that you would see the number of disk reads decrease, at least for a while.

You may have to tweak your merge policy to more agressivly merge the number of segments as you insert documents, or schedule optimizations during non peak times.

update: As an after thought, 10 shards for a single index on a single node seems overkill. Unless you have tested other configurations already or plan to add more noes, I would advise dropping that down; perhaps as low as 1 or 2.